# Ajax dataType Json, can't get my data to be send correctly.

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, object

In my frame I have this working ajax request, 'reorder_rows' triggers a function which echo's 'function reached!'.

```
var data = {};
data['reorder_rows'] = 'test';
data['token'] = $('input[name="token"]').val(); //req to pass

$.ajax({
    url:'',
    method:'post',
    data:data,
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});

//php
public function newRowOrder(){
    echo 'function reached!';
}
```

But when I try sending more data using json datatype I'm not getting a response anymore, after checking for what went wrong $_POST['reorder_rows'] & ['token'] doesn't seem to be set. Basically the call triggers nothing. What I was trying to do is the following:

```
var new_order = [];

$('.sortable').children().each(function(i){
    new_order.push({
        'id':$(this).data('id'),
        'val':parseInt($(this).find('.overview-number').val()),
    });
});

var data = {
    'reorder_rows': new_order,
    'token': $('input[name="token"]').val(),
};

$.ajax({
    url:'',
    method:'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:data,
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

All I need to go on is to get the post var 'reorder_rows' to be set properly, but honestly the code above smells a bit fishy to me.. objects into and array into an object?

I've used Json before and the sending/receiving went fine, including all the encoding/decoding stuff. But it didn't involve such data arrays. Here is a working example...

```
data['id'] = $('#id').val(); //used to exclude current item in double checks
data['form_checks'] = "";
data['token'] = $('input[name="token"]').val();

$.ajax({
    url:'',
    method:'post',
    dataType:'json',
    data:data,
    success: function(data){
        //stuff here is being done
    }
});
```

Anyone knows how I can send the data from my overview rows? I need each row's ID and (old) order number. The rows are already ordered in the html when my function triggers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_encode()` in the PHP code to return JSON:

```
public function newRowOrder() {
    echo json_encode("function reached!");
}
```

Comment: I wish it was that easy :( but sadly, the function is never reached. the $_POST vars 'reorder_rows' & 'token' aren't set. But I do infact, need to do that before I forget it!

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The `method:` option was added in 1.9.0, before that it was called `type:`.

Comment: What does reading the `$_POST` variables have to do with returning JSON?

Comment: seems to be 3.1.0, I just stumbled on some functions, JSON.stringify and json.parse... I think I need to look into those?

Comment: Your issue is with the parameter, not the response. POST parameters aren't sent as JSON, they're sent in www-form-urlencoded format.

Comment: `$_POST['reorder_row']` should be a 2-dimensional array. What does `var_dump($_POST);` show?

Comment: it says : array(0) { }.  If I use it within if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') I get 0 response

Comment: Check the Network tab in Developer Tools to see what parameters you're sending in the AJAX request.

Comment: My pc must be screwing with me today... Ive had this earlier today -.O that suddenly stuff works and having absolutely no idea what changed. Is there some memory problem or something? Weird, because as soon as I add another var_dump, the target function doesnt echo anymore

Comment: I was just able to echo the first row  with id and value: echo json_encode($view_results[0]['id'].' '.$view_results[0]['val']). I can work with it now, tnx! Maybe you have any idea why my project could not be responding on changes?  I have my chache disabled, and working localy with mamp and atom

Comment: I have no idea, you haven't provided enough information for me to even guess. There's no caching of POST requests.

Comment: a well, the next time something weird happens I will first check on my laptop :S or ask 1 of my teachers lol. easier to show em all the files

Comment: could there be a virus or something else screwing with the communication between the server and the browser? =/

Comment: Anything is theoretically possible. But a bug in your code seems more likely.

Comment: In my models I had some function chaining going on, and to be able to do this I was using return $this in these functions. Now when I was building this new script to update the multiple rows, I stumbled upon this older updateorder function (which was using the chains), and decided to use this.. but with all the slide rows, there were like 20 return $this going on... -.O It actualy did the updates, but refused to return the json encoded data... Now I made a light separate update query for this new function, and its running like a train.

Comment: Only problem I have now occurs when I am dragging the rows realy quick after each other... In my .done function I receive the new order values and inject them into the html.. but if im dragging a row at the same time, it gives an error. Afterwards it will still function, but that row will keep its error

Comment: Sounds like you need to prevent the user from dragging until you get the AJAX response and update the DOM. Otherwise he'll be modifying something that's out of date.